# Rails custom alphabetical sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wanted to sort the query alphabetically, but in a custom order

```
User
  .includes(:teachers)
  .sort_by(&:location)
```

Location is a code example A, B, C, D

But I want to sort location in A, D, C, B.

Comment: It is entiely unclear what kind of an order "A, D, C, B" is. The question is unanswerable without more details, preferably with some real (or at least realistic) sample data.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby on Rails 7.0 introduced the [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#in_order_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of) method that allows doing these kinds of custom ordering in the database like this:

```
User
  .includes(:teachers)
  .in_order_of(location: [A, D, C, B])
```

The `[A, D, C, B]` array has to be replaced with useful objects, for example, a list of location names when the `location` attribute has the datatype string.

Comment: This is a nice addition. Those using rails < 7.0 the underlying [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L664) is fairly straight forward so it shouldn't be hard to build out a functional equivalent. [MySql](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L141) has its own more efficient solution as well due to the fact that MySQL has this function built in.

Answer (score 1):

If your sort order is arbitrary like in your example (A, D, C, B), you'll have to define it somewhere.

```rb
LOCATION_ORDER = {
  'A' => 0,
  'D' => 1,
  'C' => 2,
  'B' => 3,
}
```

Then, you can sort by that.

```rb
User
  .includes(:teachers)
  .sort_by { |u| LOCATION_ORDER[u.location] }
```

It's worth noting that `sort_by` will perform the sort in your Ruby application, *not the database*, but since you're using `sort_by` already, I'll assume that's OK with you.